# How to drop subheaders in wikipedia tables?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, header, wikipedia

I am trying to web scrap a wikipedia table into a dataframe. In the wikipedia table, I want to drop Population density, Land Area, and specifically Population (Rank). In the end I want to keep State or territory and just Population (People).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_states_and_territories_of_the_United_States_by_population_density

Here is my code:

```
    wiki = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_states_and_territories_of_the_United_States_by_population_density"
    table_class="wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter"
    response=requests.get(wiki)
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    indiatable=soup.find('table',{'class':"wikitable"})

    df=pd.read_html(str(indiatable))
    df=pd.DataFrame(df[0])
    
    data = df.drop(["Population density","Population"["Rank"],"Land area"], axis=1)
   
    wikidata = data.rename(columns={"State or territory": "State","Population": "Population"})
    print (wikidata.head())
```

How to do I reference specifically that subtable header to drop the rank in Population?

Comment: Please expand on your current approach, what behavior you're expecting, and what is actually happening. It seems your are using `df.drop` so what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** *There is no expected result in your question, so you may have to make some adjustments to your headers. Assuming you like to rename `people` to `population` and not population by itself I changed that.*

To get your goal, simply set the `header` parameter while reading the html to choose only the second, so you do not need to drop it separatly:

```
df=pd.read_html(str(indiatable),header=1)[0]
df = df.rename(columns={"State or territory": "State","People": "Population"}).drop(['Rank'], axis=1)
```

#### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

wiki = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_states_and_territories_of_the_United_States_by_population_density"
table_class="wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter"
response=requests.get(wiki)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
indiatable=soup.find('table',{'class':"wikitable"})

df=pd.read_html(str(indiatable),header=1)[0]
df = df.rename(columns={"State or territory": "State","People": "Population"}).drop(['Rank'], axis=1)
```

#### Output

| State | Rank(all) | Rank(50 states) | permi2 | perkm2 | Population | Rank.1 | mi2 | km2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| District of Columbia | 1 | — | 11295 | 4361 | 689545 | 56 | 61 | 158 |
| New Jersey | 2 | 1 | 1263 | 488 | 9288994 | 46 | 7354 | 19046.8 |
| Rhode Island | 3 | 2 | 1061 | 410 | 1097379 | 51 | 1034 | 2678 |
| Puerto Rico | 4 | — | 960 | 371 | 3285874 | 49 | 3515 | 9103.8 |
| Massachusetts | 5 | 3 | 901 | 348 | 7029917 | 45 | 7800 | 20201.9 |
| Connecticut | 6 | 4 | 745 | 288 | 3605944 | 48 | 4842 | 12540.7 |
| Guam | 7 | — | 733 | 283 | 153836 | 52 | 210 | 543.9 |
| American Samoa | 8 | — | 650 | 251 | 49710 | 55 | 77 | 199.4 |